# iMac error: "Cannot run ActiveX component"

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I recently purchased an iMac and moved my EXCEL workbook from Windows. I had this macro set up to import data from a website.

It is no longer working, returning the error

> "Cannot run ActiveX component"

I looked for the "Import Data -> From a website" button on the Mac OS X version of Excel but I cannot find it. Apparently this is not possible.

```
Sub GetTeamLinks()
Dim HTMLdoc As Object, PageSource As String, url As String, i&, Arr, j&, Tbl
url = "http://mwatch.boursakuwait.com.kw/default.aspx/AllShares"

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", url, True
    .send
    
    While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend 'Check for any connection errors.
    
    If .statusText <> "OK" Then
        MsgBox "ERROR" & .Status & " - " & .statusText, vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    PageSource = .responseText
End With

Set HTMLdoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
HTMLdoc.body.innerHTML = PageSource
HTMLdoc.Close

For Each Tbl In HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("table")
    If Tbl.className = "gridtablethin" Then
        
        ReDim Arr(1 To Tbl.Rows.Length, 1 To Tbl.Rows(0).Cells.Length)
        For j = 2 To 86
            For i = 2 To UBound(Arr, 1)
                If UCase(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "B")) = Tbl.Rows(i - 1).Cells(0).innerText Then _
                    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, "F") = Tbl.Rows(i - 1).Cells(1).innerText
            Next
        Next
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Mac OS explicitly prohibits use of any ActiveX controls as a security measure.

Comment: I *think* this might point you in the right direction, on how to query data from Excel for Mac http://www.agentjim.com/MVP/Excel/WebQueryHowTo.html

Answer (score 0):

try deleting:

```
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
.Open "GET", url, True
.send
```

and replacing it with:

```
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "http://mwatch.boursakuwait.com.kw/default.aspx/AllShares"
```